# VS2013 .NET 4.51 nuget -Install CassandraCSharpDriver fails

Tags: c#-4.0, cassandra, nuget-package

My goal is to write a C# program to test with Cassandra database.

In VS2013, I've tried .NET 4.51, 4.5, 4.0, and even 3.5.  With 4.5 this is the error I get:

> PM> Install-Package CassandraCSharpDriver Attempting to resolve
>   dependency 'lz4net (≥ 1.0.10.93)'. Attempting to resolve dependency
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging (≥ 1.0.0)'. Attempting to resolve
>   dependency 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions (≥ 1.0.0)'.
>   Installing 'lz4net 1.0.15.93'. Successfully installed 'lz4net
>   1.0.15.93'. Installing 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 1.0.2'. You are downloading Microsoft.Extensions.Logging from
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, the license agreement to which is
>   available at
>   http://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/eula/net_library_eula_enu.htm.
>   Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with
>   their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and
>   dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements.
>   If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the
>   relevant components from your device. Successfully installed
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 1.0.2'. Installing
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 1.0.2'. You are downloading
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions from
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, the license agreement to
>   which is available at
>   http://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/eula/net_library_eula_enu.htm.
>   Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with
>   their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and
>   dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements.
>   If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the
>   relevant components from your device. Successfully installed
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 1.0.2'. Installing
>   'CassandraCSharpDriver 3.2.1'. Successfully installed
>   'CassandraCSharpDriver 3.2.1'. Adding 'lz4net 1.0.15.93' to
>   CassandraTester. Successfully added 'lz4net 1.0.15.93' to
>   CassandraTester. Adding 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 1.0.2' to
>   CassandraTester. Uninstalling 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 1.0.2'.
>   Successfully uninstalled 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 1.0.2'.
>   Uninstalling 'lz4net 1.0.15.93'. Successfully uninstalled 'lz4net
>   1.0.15.93'. Install failed. Rolling back... Install-Package : **Could not install package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 1.0.2'. You are
>   trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does  not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework.** For more information, contact the package author. At line:1
>   char:1
>   + Install-Package CassandraCSharpDriver
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

PM>

Comment: I'm trying other packages - it's totally unclear to me which one to use: http://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/Cassandra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far my get-around has been to go back to a prior version:

> Install-Package CassandraCSharpDriver -Version 3.1.0

I found the version history here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/CassandraCSharpDriver

At least it installed now.

Comment: I marked my answer correct, but if anyone knows how to get the current version working, I will switch the correct answer to that one.